Align-items : The children elements are getting bigger
I'm using VueJS.
When I try to align vertically the sub-elements of a flexbox, using align-items : center, the children of a child flexbox are getting bigger.
HTML:
 <div class="modal" v-show="this.estModalOuverte">
    <div class="autres-vues" v-if="fauteuilSelectionne.images">
      <img
        v-for="image in autresVues"
        class="vignette-autres-vues"
        :src="require(`@/img/${image}`)"
        :key="image"
      />
    </div>
    <img
      v-if="fauteuilSelectionne.images"
      class="image-affichee"
      :src="require(`@/img/${this.fauteuilSelectionne.images[0]}`)"
    />
  </div>

CSS:
.modal {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  width: 80%;
  height: 85%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-affichee {
  height: 80%;
}

.autres-vues {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.vignette-autres-vues {
  height: 18%;
  margin: 1rem 4rem;
}

Here is the result I get :
Image with the bug on align-items:center
and the state of the website before using align-items: center
Initial state of the website
I don't understand what'a happening and how to solve this.
Some ideas ?
Best regards.

tracking the size of your .autres-vues class might help, try to change background color on it for instance. it seems it's taking all the screen space since its parent position is set to absolute.

The problem was height  : 18% was not efficient. I switched to width and it worked.
Thanks for your answer, it helped me to find it out !
